# How do I add additional class on hover in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have several circles with a css class of rating-circle and I want to add an additional class. Here is the code I'm using.

```
    $(function () {

        //change class on hover

        $('.rating-circle').hover( function() {
            $('.rating-circle')addClass('rating-hover');
        });
    });
```

What did I miss?

Comment: maybe a dot (".") :
$('.rating-circle').addClass('rating-hover');
                           ^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot the dot

```
$('.rating-circle').addClass('rating-hover');
```

Small advice: Use some developer tool when you are working in frontEnd, and those minor mistakes are really easy to fix :)

Comment: Thanks cralfaro. I missed the darn dot.

Comment: @martinbshp no worries is very common mistake in frontEnd :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$('.rating-circle').hover( function() {
        $(this).addClass('rating-hover');
    });
```

Comment: dot is missing `addClass()` check it out and this was the only error PO Missing

Comment: Thanks for directing http://stackoverflow.com/users/4193004/bharat-patidar. Now I have corrected it.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can add by space delimited classes.

```js
$(function () {
  //change class on hover
  $('.rating-circle').hover( function() {
    $('.rating-circle').addClass('rating-hover another-class');
    //-----------------^ Also a typo here.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this, `$(this)` will add the class to the `hover element` only. not to the others with the same class name.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //change class on hover
    $('.rating-circle').hover( function() {
        $(this).addClass('rating-hover');
    });

});
```

Comment: I have already answered the same. Please Provide another option.